# advantage of creating a temporary buffer when iterating over and modifying a collection in java

Tags: java, collections, enums, dictionary

I am iterating over, and modifying a map (which is created from an existing group of enum objects) like the following:

```
public class Dispenser {
   private Map<Ingredient, Integer> availableIngredients = 
         new EnumMap<Ingredient, Integer>(Ingredient.class);
   public void orderSandwich(SandwichType sandwichType) {
      Map<Ingredient, Integer> buffer = 
            new EnumMap<Ingredient, Integer>(availableIngredients);
      for (Map.Entry<Ingredient, Integer> entry : 
            sandwichType.getIngredients().entrySet()) {
         Integer currentUnits = buffer.get(entry.getKey());
         buffer.put(entry.getKey(), currentUnits - entry.getValue());
      }     
      availableIngredients.clear();
      availableIngredients.putAll(buffer);
   }
}
```

I wanted to ask if the temporary, method-local, **buffer** collection is necessary in this case. I mean, it works fine as it is but not sure its benefits. I have to clear my original collection and replace it with the contents of the buffer collection, which is basically the actual map that is modified within the loop.

Since, it works fine without the buffer collection (using only my original collection), I was wondering if one approach is recommended over the oter and why.

Many thanks for any advice on best practices on this.

Comment: Your question is basically, "I'm adding 2 and 2 like this: 2 + 3 + 2 - 3.  It works but I'm unclear on the benefits of adding and subtracting the 3."

You really haven't explained why this seemed like it was needed in the first place.  Why aren't you just modifying availableIngredients directly?  I assume, from the "toy-program" appearance, that you're not concerned about multiple threads?

Incidentally, it looks like you'd benefit from using an EnumMultiset from google-collections.googlecode.com instead of a Map, but that's irrelevant if this is a school project, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `buffer` map. You can operate on `availableIngredients` instead. Everything will be fine. With no useless overhead.

Comment: So what of the ConcurrentModificationException risk, mentioned in the previous answer?

Comment: I didn't happen, I am just trying understand the advantage of using a copy/buffer collection. I suppose in this case there is no advantage because there is no concurrent functionality

Comment: But then again, I imaging what dtsazza was referring to, was not two different threads operating on the collection at the same time, but rather only one thread would be doing two operations at the same time, meaning iterating and modifying at the same time

Comment: You don't iterate over availableIngredients so you can modify it.

Comment: joel - it was misreading on my part - Mykola is right.  The pattern *looks* like the was to avoid CMEs, but it turns out it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's like to avoid [ConcurrentModificationException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)s.

You cannot modify a collection while iterating over it, or such an exception will be thrown.  What you have posted is a not-uncommon idiom for dealing with this - take a copy of the collection in one way or another, then you can iterate over one while modifying the other.

This can happen even in single-threaded code - for example, something like this will throw that exception on a collection with at least two elements:

```
for (Object o : myCollection)
{
   myCollection.remove(o);
}
```

An alternative, and likely more performant, way to deal with this is to explicitly declare the Iterator (rather than using the *foreach* loop), and then use the Iterator's [remove](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) method, if appropriate.  (This doesn't apply to your case, though, because you're remapping rather than removing elements).

Edit: On reflection though, the `availableIngredients` map isn't being looped over so can simply be modified directly.  You're right to be confused as it turns out. :-)  Chances are this is vestigial from former refactoring, but it can be replaced by

```
public void orderSandwich(SandwichType sandwichType) {
  for (Map.Entry<Ingredient, Integer> entry : 
        sandwichType.getIngredients().entrySet()) {
     Integer currentUnits = availableIngredients.get(entry.getKey());
     availableIngredients.put(entry.getKey(), currentUnits - entry.getValue());
  }         
}
```

as you no doubt expect.

A thought that's just come to mind is that this might also have been a misguided attempt to make concurrency problems "less likely", by reducing the window of conflicting updates.  Misguided, though, because threadsafety is absolute; making something ten times less likely to exhibit data races is not a good investment of time.  It will still fail, "randomly", and is thus incorrect.

Comment: I didn't get. Where did he modify collection while iterating?

Comment: Thanks, will the ConcurrentModificationException be thrown by the collection even if concurrency is not addressed at all? I mean, my application is not multithreaded, so there couldn't be more than one thread operating on the same collection at the same time

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. The method is iterating over sandwichType.getIngredients() and modifying availableIngredients. Perhaps an earlier version was iterating and modifying the same collection, but I don't think it's necessary here.

Comment: -1 he's iterating over the sandwich ingredients and modifying the *available* ingredients.

Comment: @Don Kirkby: Yes, you are right. I am iterating over a collection and actually modifying another - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a buffer in this case, as you iterate over the collection `sandwichType.getIngredients()` while modifying `availableIngredients` these are separate collections.

For the cases where using a buffer is a good idea, replacing the original can be done easier like this:

```
  availableIngredients = buffer;
```

there is no need to update the original collection, it suffices to use the new version from now on.